# keeping the date the doc was made

Tags: microsoft-word

I use word 2010
i open a blank page and design a form where someone can take notes, like a header i use the date input so it would automatic put date in. and saved it as a template.

say someone downloads the template from our church website the next day, how do i fix it where the date that the doc was made stay the same

say the service was sunday 1-26-14 that is the date on the doc,
two days later tuesday 1-28-14 they down load the doc. from web site the doc automatic updates the that day. how do you fix where the date that the service is on stays that way

Comment: so you want the file name to change to include the current date? or you want to the actual document in word to change to the current date when the member downloads it?

Answer (score 1):

How you enter this depends on your version of Word.  Currently, you seem to be using the `DATE` field, whereas you should probably be using the `CREATEDATE` field:

```
 { CREATEDATE [ \@ "Date-Time Picture"] [Switches]}
```

This will retain the create date of the document, rather than the current date.

There is more information [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/help/field-codes-createdate-field-HP010260103.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010100426).  However you inserted the `DATE` field, look for an alternative called `CREATEDATE`.